# A question about convergence to infinity of a sequence of integrals of functions with complex values

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, complex-integration

I have a fixed real number $t\neq 0$ and a function with complex values but defined in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$\ell: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}, \quad \ell(x) = e^{itx} - 1$$
For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, I have a measure $M_n$ defined on the borelians of $\mathbb{R}$, such that:
$$M_n \Big( \left[-\delta,\delta\right] \Big) = k_n, \quad k_n \uparrow\infty\,\, (n \to \infty)$$
for some $\delta>0$ fixed.

I want to show that
$$\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \ell(x) M_n d(x)\to \infty \quad (n \to \infty)$$

I'm trying to limit this integral to a lower bound that converges to infinity. For this, I'm trying to use $k_n$, but I don't know how to do that.

Help!

**Update:**

In fact, $M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \infty$ with $M_n$ being a Lévy measure:

1. $\forall \delta > 0,\,\, \exists \, C_\delta< \infty, \,\, M_n(\mathbb{R} \setminus B_{\delta} (0) ) \leq C_\delta,\,\, \forall n$ and
2. $\exists \, C_0 < \infty, \, \int_{ |x| \leq 1} x^2 M_n (dx)< C_0,\,\, \forall n.$.

Futhermore, $M_n(E) = \sum_{j=1}^n \mu_{nj}(E)$ where $\mu_{nj}$ is not a dirac measure. This is in the context of the generalization of the central limit theorem for array of independent random variable!

Answer (score 1):

As stated this is false. (Perhaps some crucial hypothesis is missing). Let $M_n=n\delta_0$. The $M_n[-\delta,\delta]=n \to \infty$ but $\int l(x)dM_n(x)=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: In fact, $M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \infty$ with $M_n$ being a Lévy measure:  1) $\forall \delta > 0,\,\, \exists \, C_\delta< \infty, \,\, M_n( \mathbb{R} \setminus B_{\delta} (0) ) \leq C_\delta,\,\, \forall n$ and 2) $\exists \, C_0 < \infty, \, \int_{ |x| \leq 1} x^2 M_n (dx)< C_0,\,\, \forall n.$.

Comment: Kavi, in fact $M_n(E) = \sum_{j=1}^n \mu_{nj}(E)$ where $\mu_{nj}$ is not a dirac measure. This is in the context of the generalization of the central limit theorem for array of independent random variable! Indeed, I want to analyze the convergence of $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \ell(x) dM_n (x)$.  I think the problematic part is around zero.

Comment: Your claim is false for a Levy measuer $\nu$ with $\int \min \{1,|x|\}d\nu <\infty$. @PSE